# php send email with runtime created file

Tags: php, email, attached-properties

I have to create files in xlsx and pdf and want to send as attached with email(do not want to save anywhere).i know how to attached a saved file and send in email.
how can i send it direclty without saving.here is what i tried

```
$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)));
 $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: application/doc; name=\"$file\"\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"$file\"\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: application/docx; name=\"$file\"\r\n"
  ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
  ."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= $attachment;
  $message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

  //send the email
 $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers );
```

now i do not have $path,i am generating contents on same file ..what to do to send it with out saving?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just base64 encode some data that isn't stored in a file you can just do this (where `$data` is the file you have generated):

```
$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```

Comment: i am generating pdf and xlsx at runtime and want to send in email as attached...can i do it with out saving at server?

Comment: @user2244804 generating how?

Comment: i have data saved in mysql table..i want to send it as pdf/xlsx via email...for example if i have user's record.i want it to send to admin via email

Comment: You just need to get the file data (however its stored in your database (BLOB?)) into a variable (in this case `$data`) and use `base64_encode` on it (shown in my example).